# How to check if function is exist or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the class has a method or not in javascript. Suppose for checking normal function I can use like - 
Using Jquery:

```
function foo(){}
if($.isFunction(foo)) alert('exists');
```

Or from normal javascript:

```
function foo(){}
if(typeof foo != 'undefined') alert('exists');
```

But I want to check for a member function like if I have a class and method like-

```
function ClassName(){
 //Some code
}

ClassName.prototype.foo = function(){};
```

And I have a method name stored in a variable, and I am calling the method using this variable like-

```
var call_it = 'foo';
new ClassName()[call_it]();
```

But for the handling runtime error, I want to check the method exist or not before calling. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var call_it = 'foo';
if (typeof ClassName.prototype[call_it] === "function"){
   new ClassName()[call_it]();
}
```

OR

```
 var call_it = 'foo';
 var instance = new ClassName();
 if (typeof instance[call_it] === "function"){
     instance[call_it]();
 }
```

You should use **typeof** to ensure the property exists ***and is a function***

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ClassName.prototype[call_it]) {
    new ClassName()[call_it]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( typeof yourClass.foo == 'function' ) { 
    yourClass.foo(); 
}
```